# openvpn: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0

Tags: openvpn, openssl

I am unable to connect to my organization after I updated to ubuntu20.04

When i try to connect I get `openvpn: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have OpenSSL 1.1.1f and unable to downgrade as I get `Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`

I tried `wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7531893/+files/openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_amd64.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.31_amd64.deb`

but I get `dpkg: error processing package openssl (--install):`

Comment: How did you install OpenVPN?

Comment: I did not explicitly install it after the upgrade to 20.04. I installed it from the distributions while I was in 18.04 by `sudo apt-get install openvpn`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy openvpn` and `whereis openvpn`?

Comment: it is in `/usr/local/sbin/openvpn`

Comment: Please run both commands I provided and [edit] your question to include the information. While what you provided provide hints, it's not *enough* to diagnose it fully.

Comment: If you have it in `/usr/local`, it's not an official Ubuntu version. Get rid of that one, and I bet it will work.

Comment: apt policy openvpn     : `openvpn:
  Installed: 2.4.7-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.7-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: `openvpn: /usr/sbin/openvpn /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openvpn /etc/openvpn /usr/local/sbin/openvpn /usr/local/lib/openvpn /usr/include/openvpn /usr/share/openvpn /usr/share/man/man8/openvpn.8.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have OpenVPN not installed through Ubuntu's repositories. You likely installed a version manually at some point.

1. Remove the old, local, version with `sudo rm -f /usr/local/sbin/openvpn`
2. Install from the repositories with `sudo apt install openvpn`

The first command removes the binary, which is probably compiled against old version of OpenSSL. The second command ensures that you have the latest version of OpenVPN from Ubuntu repositories installed.

---

*All* software provided through the standard repositories land in `/usr`. Software installed manually from source tends to end up in `/usr/local`. This is a convention - to keep separate things separate. This is a feature - but can be confusing to new users. `whereis` command locates all instances of this filename in your path - in your case showing that you have multiple versions installed.

`apt policy` shows information about what's installed and what's available in the repositories, thus verifying that the version installed is in fact the newest, and not left over from before a upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed description and it has fixed my issue.

Comment: Then please mark it as accepted answer by pressing the checkmark under the score :)